# DS3231 and EEPROM

Tags: eeprom, rtc

Currently to get time/date i'm using DS3231 module with the [RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib) library, i want to use the Atmel 24C32 chip on the module to store some small values (temperature etc).

Can i use the current library AND an external EEPROM library (which one?) OR i need to change my RTC library in order to use EEPROM feature?

Comment: why not use the EEPROM of your MCU?

Comment: @Juraj because built in EEPROM have a limited number that can be write, i think it's 100,000 times.

Comment: every EEPROM has 'limited' count of writes. you have an Arduino Uno with removable ATmega328?

Comment: @Juraj yes but 24C32 have write cycle of 1 million times instead of 100,000 times of ATmega328.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use the current library AND an external EEPROM library (which one?)

Yes. Devices on an I2C bus are separate devices and use their own separate libraries.

- https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryForI2CEEPROM/

Comment: [is this](https://github.com/QuentinCG/Arduino-I2C-EEPROM-library) a proper library to use?

Comment: It's the first hit on Google so I guess so. I don't use Arduino and have my own chipKIT DTWI based library so I don't know.

Comment: **just in case anyone stumble upon this question; i tested [this library](https://github.com/QuentinCG/Arduino-I2C-EEPROM-library) and it's working.**